# Good all character combinations using a given length

Tags: character

Is there a program/tool/utility that would allow me to generate all possible character combinations (lowercase, uppercase, symbols, numbers) over a given length of characters (min-max)?

Comment: if you are interesting in building your own solution, a question has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same field as brute-force password cracking, which might be what you are trying to achieve.  Wikipedia has a reasonable article on [password cracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_cracking), and lists the most popular software for the task.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a code, just strong passwords you can try to use some services:

http://onlinepasswordgenerator.net

http://h4sher.net

techzoom.net/tools/password-generator.en

Answer (score 0):

Online:

- [Javascript Permutation Generator](http://scriptar.com/JavaScript/permute.html)
- [Permutation of strings](http://www.digsys.se/js_permut.html)

Desktop:

- [Free Password Generator](http://free-random-password-generator.free-random-password-generator-com.qarchive.org/). It's a password generator tool but you are able to

  - fix the length
  - choose to include letters/digits/catpital letters

    [alt text http://free-random-password-generator.free-random-password-generator-com.qarchive.org/mainscreen350.png](http://free-random-password-generator.free-random-password-generator-com.qarchive.org/mainscreen350.png)