# permutations and combinations

Tags: c

I have a program which creates some combinations of strings like if I entered input `abc` it gives me output as `bca` `cab` `abc`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[15];
    int i,j,n;

    printf("Enter a string");
    scanf("%s",str);
    n=strlen(str);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        str[n]=str[0];

        for(j=0;j<n;j++)    
        {
            str[j]=str[j-1];
        }
    str[n]='\0';
    printf("\n %s \n",str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I want a program which gives me all possible combinations of a string
so what are the changes I need to make?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string

Comment: Unless the number of letters in `str` is fixed to a small value (and 14 as in your code is not very small), you'd better use recursion at some point, otherwise it might get tedious.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Exeter algorithm](http://www.bearcave.com/random_hacks/permute.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char *x, char *y){
    char w;
    w = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = w;
}

void permute(char *str, int start, int n){
    int i;

    if(start == n-1)
        printf("%s\n", str);
    else
        for(i = start; i < n; i++){
            swap(str+i, str+start);
            permute(str, start+1, n);
            swap(str+i, str+start);
        }
}

int main(){

    char line[10], str[10];
    int n, op;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    if( fgets(line, 10, stdin) == NULL ){
        printf("Ops! Early stop\n");
        return 1;
    }


    if( sscanf(line, "%s", str) != 1 ){
        printf("Next time put some valid characters\n");
        return 1;
    }

    n = strlen(str);
    permute(str, 0, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: This algorithm generates all the possibles **permutations**