# Creating A List of Possible String Combination

Tags: .net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Generate list of all possible permutations of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string)

I need to work on a small algorithm project where I need to be able to list and write to a text file the possible combination of a given set of characters based on a given limit.

For example, if I enter the characters "a", "b", and "c" and set the limit to 3 the possible output would be:

```
a
b
c
aa
bb
cc
ab
ac
ba
bc
ca
cb
...
    aaa
    bbb
    ccc
    ...
    ...
    abc
    acb
    bac
    bca
    cab
    cba
```

Until all possible combinations have been devised.

Writing this to a text file is no problem with me. Having an algorithm that would write the combination is something that I am quite not good at.

Appreciate in .NET (C# or VB) codes.

Thanks.

PS

On a side note, I wonder how long it would take for an application to create a string combination of all possible keyboard characters and how big the file would get to be.

Updated:
I should also show character combination from n characters to the implied limit..

Comment: quick google search for "character combination algorithm" found this discussion (this was the first hit in a list of other good-looking candidates) where they outline an algorithm: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread110604.html

Comment: There are `n**b` unique permutations of `n` items from a set of size `b`. (in particular, this tells you how many numbers n digits in base b can represent (e.g. 5 bits: `2**5 == 32`)). Even assuming ASCII (95 printable chars), there are 857,375 3-letter, 81,450,625 4-letter, (and so on) strings. This grows expotentially. And nowadaws, you have codepages with 256 chars or even Unicode. For many purposes, there are much cheaper solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate all the permutations in a string using a recursive implementation. A quick but functional implementation might look like the following:

**Edit:** You changed the OP to include strings with length less than the input character set. The following code has been modified. It gives exactly the output in your question.

```
static void BuildPermutations(string input, char[] current, int index, int depth, List<string> perms)
{
    if (index == depth)
    {
        perms.Add(new string(current, 0, depth));
        return;
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < input.Length; ++n)
    {
        current[index] = input[n];
        BuildPermutations(input, current, index + 1, depth, perms);
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "abc";
    char[] current = new char[input.Length];
    List<string> perms = new List<string>();
    for (int n = 1; n <= 3; ++n )
        BuildPermutations(input, current, 0, n, perms);
    foreach (string s in perms)
        System.Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See [Generate list of all possible permutations of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for your example, I might try something like this.

```
string chars = "abc";

for (int a = 0; a < chars.Length; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < chars.Length; b++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < chars.Length; c++)
        {
            string row = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", chars[a], chars[b], chars[c]);
        }
    }
}
```

That's just typed here so it may contain errors. Also, I'm not sure if the character limit is tied to the number of possible characters. But perhaps this will give you a starting point.