# Simple Number generator logic

Tags: java

I have a number 0127

i am trying logic to generate number following sequence in JAVA

```
0
1
2
7
01
12
27
012
127
0127
1270
2701
7012
01270
12701
27012
.
.
```

I am breaking my head :-)

Comment: I'm assuming this is homework?

Comment: yeah.. Sorry guys I spent much time i couldn't get this silly thing

Comment: Do you see any patterns? What have you figured out so far?

Comment: My progress ..0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7...50...6,5,4,3,2,0-> this is where iam

Comment: @Soft - is it that you can't figure out the pattern, or you're having problems with the code, or both? Post what you *think* the pattern is.

Comment: The problem is to generate all possible combination of the digit for the given number. Example is given above. I couldn't find the pattern

Comment: Er ... that's not what the output you posted is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate list of all possible permutations of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string)

Comment: @Brian, the list isn't every possible permutation, because the patter is that you must maintain the original ordering of the string.  E.g., 0127 is acceptable where as 0217 isn't

Comment: @joe - my ESP must be on the fritz, sorry :) He threw me with that last comment. It's what I originally thought then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the number to a `String` object, then to an array of chars.

From there, you can iterate over the array with the following logic:

```
        int MAX_LENGTH = 10;
        char[] array = "0127".ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            for (int offset = 0; offset < array.Length; offset++)
            {
                String disp = "";
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    int index = j + offset;
                    while (index >= array.Length)
                        index -= array.Length;
                    disp += array[index];
                }
                Console.WriteLine(disp);
            }
        }
```

Change `MAX_LENGTH` to be what ever the maximum length of the output string should be.

Here is the output that this code produces:
[image]

Comment: Errr, this is not Java and it does not produce the same sequence (but I still think, that Soft's question misses some numbers - so the algorithm, translated to Java, may be the one that solves the problem ;) )

Comment: I did minor change to this and i got the result i expect

Comment: I forgot to change the `if` to a `while` on the interior.  I updated it and posted a picture of the results. @Andreas, I believe that it does produce the same sequence :)

Comment: As  I said, I was sure, it's the solution, but 70, 270 and 701 are not in the question's sequence. @Soft - please double-check your question!!

Answer (score 1):

**Divide it up into two steps: the substrings and superstrings.**

Sometimes the best way to solve a big problem is to divide the work up into smaller problems that are easier to solve.

For the substrings, use nested for loops.

1. Loop substring length from `1` to `string.length() - 1`
2. Loop starting character from `0` to `string.length() - 1 - substringLength`

In the inner loop, generate the substring of the given length from the given starting character.  This will generate all the substrings.

For the superstrings, you only need one loop to pick the starting character.  For each item in the loop, start at that character and build your string until the given length, wrapping from the last character to the first.

Comment: I had to think about this more than the actual problem. Just sayin' :)

Comment: +1 for thinking about it more than the actual problem! I figured `O(n^3)` is acceptable runtime complexity for homework

Comment: All of the posted answers are `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 1):

The first few lines starting from `0` to `0127` (inclusively) are all subsequences of `{0,1,2,7}` (empty set is missing).

For the rest - it's like a *ring*, you pick a starting number and "go" `n` steps in one direction:

```
               0
              / \
             7   1
              \ /
               2
```

this would produce:

```
n=1: 0,    1,    2,    7
n=2: 01,   12,   27,   70
n=3: 012,  127,  270,  701
n=4: 0127, 1270, 2701, 7012
```

But I can't see a link between the two parts - are you sure, the sequence in your question is complete, no numbers missing? especially 70, 270 and 701?

Answer (score 1):

```
int MAX_LENGTH = 5;
        String[] numStr = {"0","1","2","7"};
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            for (int offset = 0; offset < numStr.length; offset++)
            {
                if(i>0 && offset+1 == numStr.length) continue;
                String disp = "";
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    int index = j + offset;
                    if (index >= numStr.length)
                        index -= numStr.length;
                    disp += numStr[index];
                }
                System.out.println(disp);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Sweet.  Make sure you change the line `if (index >= numStr.length) ` to `while (index >= numStr.length) `

Comment: The output is not the same as in your question

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It was executed with the tested number and it generates the same sequence:

```
public static void printSequence(String number) {
    final char[] charNumber = number.toCharArray();
    final int sizeNumber = number.length();

    int MAX_ITER = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITER; i++) {
        for (int offset = 0; offset < sizeNumber; offset++) {
            String subSequence = "";
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                int index = (j + offset) % sizeNumber;
                subSequence += charNumber[index];
            }
            System.out.println(subSequence);
        }
    }
}
```