# How to find exact matches between rows in two columns?

Tags: r

There are two columns in my dataset. It contains 33000 rows (huge).
column 1 is called "Surname"
column 2 is called "nickname"

I need to find out how many peoples surname is exactly the same as their nickname.
can anyone find me a function for this in R??

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can just simply create an logical test of equality between the two columns. After that, if you sum the logical values that result from this test, you get the number of TRUE's, or the number of rows, that have the same surname/nickname.

```
tab <- data.frame(
  nickname = sample(c("Ana", "Tese", "Maker"), size = 20, replace = TRUE),
  surname = sample(c("Ana", "Ed", "Philip"), size = 20, replace = TRUE)
)

tab$test <- tab$nickname == tab$surname

sum(tab$test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fàîžà!

My solution involves creating a new column in your dataframe which indicates TRUE if the surname and nickname are *exactly the same* and FALSE if they are not *exactly the same*.

To do this, you need the *dplyr* package:

```
surname <- c("Smith", "Potter", "Smith") 
nickname <- c("Bobby", "Potter", "Smith")
df <- data.frame(surname = x, nickname = y)
```

Now that we have the dataframe, let's add the *dplyr* code:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(equal_names = case_when(
    surname == nickname ~ TRUE, 
    surname != nickname ~ FALSE))
```

The result is:

```
> df
  surname nickname equal_names
1   Smith    Bobby       FALSE
2  Potter   Potter        TRUE
3   Smith    Smith        TRUE
```

`case_when()` returns whatever you want after the specified condition.

If you want more advanced screening, you'd need to check how regular expressions work. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379532/determine-if-two-names-are-close-to-each-other) has a few hints about this.

Comment: `if_else()` would be an alternative to `case_when()` :)

Comment: my dataset is huge like around 33000 rows :(

Comment: In that case, both `case_when` and `if_else` are unnecessary, since `==` already gives a logical vector that can be added directly as a column.

Answer (score 0):

A simple base R like below might work

```
sum(do.call("==",df))
```

**Example**

```
df <- structure(list(surname = c("A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C", 
"B", "B", "C"), nickname = c("C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))

> df
   surname nickname
1        A        C
2        C        A
3        A        A
4        B        A
5        A        B
6        C        B
7        C        B
8        B        B
9        B        C
10       C        A

> sum(do.call("==",df))
[1] 2
```