# Algorithm to create all permutations and lengths

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am looking to create an algorithm preferably in Java. I would like to go through following char array and create every possible permutations and lengths out of it.

For example, loop and print the following:

```
a
aa
aaaa
aaaaa
.... keep going ....
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ....
ab
aba
abaa .............
```

Till I hit all possible lengths and permutations from my array.

```
private void method(){
    char[] data = "abcdefghiABCDEFGHI0123456789".toCharArray();
    // loop and print each time
}
```

I think it would be silly to come up with 10s of for loops for this. I am guessing some form of recursion would help here but can't get my head around to even start with. Could I get some help with this please? Even if pointing me to a start or a blog or something. Been Googling and looking around and many permutations examples exists but keeps to fixed max length. None seems to have examples on multiple length  + permutations. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: I do not see how your example output, your description and the example code match. How is  output `aa` possible given the given `data` array? `a` occurs only once in `data`...

Comment: @MichaelKreutz This is a brute force take at a password crack. There are ready made programs out there that does this but I am trying to create how the algorithm would be written. The char array is how I imagined it would be stored. I am still expecting above output. Advice if the storage should be in a different format instead of this char array to achieve that. Thanks.

Comment: What is the longest possible and valid string length? 28?

Comment: @Eritrean It would be length of 28. Started with single 'a' and end with 999999999999999999999999.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not fully get it. What you try to find are not permutations of a given word respectively subwords of that word, but sampling with replacement, right?

Comment: @MichaelKreutz Sorry maybe am just not framing my question properly. Ignore the method. To keep it short, assume I only have 3 characters 'abc'. And I want my output to be -> a aa aaa ab aba ac aca b ba baa bb bba and so on. Will update the question if this is clarifies better.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293870/algorithm-to-get-all-possible-string-combinations-from-array-up-to-certain-lengt/15625853#15625853

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is this:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static String[] method(char[] arr, int length) {
      if(length == arr.length - 1) {
        String[] strArr = new String[arr.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
            strArr[i] = String.valueOf(arr[i]);
        }

        return strArr;
      }


      String[] before = method(arr, length + 1);
      String[] newArr = new String[arr.length * before.length];
      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < before.length; j ++) {
          if(i == 0)
            System.out.println(before[j]);

          newArr[i * before.length + j] = (arr[i] + before[j]);
        }
      }

      return newArr;
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        String[] all = method("abcde".toCharArray(), 0);

        for(int i = 0; i < all.length; i ++) {
          System.out.println(all[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

However be careful you'll probably run out of memory or the program will take a looooong time to compile/run if it does at all. You are trying to print 3.437313508041091e+40 strings, that's 3 followed by 40 zeroes.

Here's the solution also in javascript because it starts running but it needs 4 seconds to get to 4 character permutations, for it to reach 5 character permutations it will need about 28 times that time, for 6 characters it's 4 * 28 * 28 and so on.

```
const method = (arr, length) => {
  if(length === arr.length - 1)
    return arr;

  const hm = [];
  const before = method(arr, length + 1);
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < before.length; j ++) {
      if(i === 0)
        console.log(before[j]);

      hm.push(arr[i] + before[j]);
    }
  }

  return hm;
};

method('abcdefghiABCDEFGHI0123456789'.split(''), 0).forEach(a => console.log(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void method(){
    char[] data = "abcdefghiABCDEFGHI0123456789".toCharArray();
    // loop and print each time
}
```

With your given input there are `3.43731350804×10E40` combinations. (Spelled result in words is `eighteen quadrillion fourteen trillion three hundred ninety-eight billion five hundred nine million four hundred eighty-one thousand nine hundred eighty-four`. ) If I remember it correctly the maths is some how

```
1  +  x  +  x^2  +  x^3  +  x^4  +  ...  +  x^n = (1 - x^n+1) / (1 - x)
```

in your case

```
28 + 28^2 + 28^3 + .... 28^28
```

cause you will have

28 combinations for strings with length one

28*28 combinations for strings with length two

28*28*28 combinations for strings with length three

...

28^28 combinations  for strings with length 28

It will take a while to print them all.

One way I can think of is to use the Generex library, a Java library for generating String that match a given regular expression.

Generex [github](https://github.com/mifmif/Generex). Look at their page for more info.

Generex [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mifmif/generex/1.0.2). Download the jar or add dependency.

Using generex is straight forward if you are somehow familiar with regex.

Example using only the first 5 chars which will have 3905 possible combinations

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Generex generex = new Generex("[a-e]{1,5}");
    System.out.println(generex.getAllMatchedStrings().size());
    Iterator iterator = generex.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

Meaning of `[a-e]{1,5}` any combination of the chars a,b,c,d,e wit a min length of 1 and max length of 5

output

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaab
aaaac
aaaad
aaaae
aaab
aaaba
aaabb
aaabc
aaabd
aaabe
aaac
....
eeee
eeeea
eeeeb
eeeec
eeeed
eeeee
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a for loop that starts from 1 and ends at array.length and in each iteration call a function that prints all the permutations for that length.

```
public void printPermutations(char[] array, int length) {
  /*
   * Create all permutations with length = length and print them
   */
}

public void method() {
  char data = "abcdefghiABCDEFGHI0123456789".toCharArray();

  for(int i = 1; i <= data.length; i ++) {
    printPermutations(data, i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a bad answer, but I feel this is more of a comment

Answer (score 0):

I think the following recursion could solve your problem:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] data = {"a", "b", "c"};
    sampleWithReplacement(data, "", 1, 5);
  }

  private static void sampleWithReplacement(
      final String[] letters,
      final String prefix,
      final int currentLength,
      final int maxLength
  ) {
    if (currentLength <= maxLength) {
      for (String letter : letters) {
        final String newPrefix = prefix + letter;
        System.out.println(newPrefix);
        sampleWithReplacement(letters, newPrefix, currentLength + 1, maxLength);
      }

    }
  }
```

where `data` specifies your possible characters to sample from.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're talking about?

```
public class PrintPermutations
{
    public static String stream = "";

    public static void printPermutations (char[] set, int count, int length)
    {
        if (count < length)
            for (int i = 0; i < set.length; ++i)
            {
                stream += set[i];
                System.out.println (stream);

                printPermutations (set, count + 1, length);
                stream = stream.substring (0, stream.length() - 1);
            }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        char[] set = "abcdefghiABCDEFGHI0123456789".toCharArray();
        printPermutations (set, 0, set.length);
    }
}
```

Test it using a smaller string first.

Answer (score 0):

On an input string 28 characters long this method is never going to end, but for smaller inputs it will generate all permutations up to length n, where n is the number of characters. It first prints all permutations of length 1, then all of length 2 etc, which is different from your example, but hopefully order doesn't matter.

```
static void permutations(char[] arr)
{
    int[] idx = new int[arr.length];
    char[] perm = new char[arr.length];

    Arrays.fill(perm, arr[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println(new String(perm, 0, i));

            int k = i - 1;
            for (; k >= 0; k--)
            {
                idx[k] += 1;
                if (idx[k] < arr.length)
                {
                    perm[k] = arr[idx[k]];
                    break;
                }
                idx[k] = 0;
                perm[k] = arr[idx[k]];
            }
            if (k < 0)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
permutations("abc".toCharArray());
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
```