# How to get all the possible 3 letter permutations?

Tags: c#, algorithm, alphabetical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Listing all permutations of a string/integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer)

For example,

```
aaa .. aaz .. aba .. abz .. aca .. acz .. azz .. baa .. baz .. bba .. bbz .. zzz
```

Basically, imagine counting binary but instead of going from 0 to 1, it goes from a to z.

I have been trying to get this working to no avail and the formula is getting quite complex. I'm not sure if there's a simpler way to do it.

### Edit

I have something like this at the moment but it's not quite there and I'm not sure if there is a better way:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetWordsOfLength(int length)
{
    char letterA = 'a', letterZ = 'z';

    StringBuilder currentLetters = new StringBuilder(new string(letterA, length));
    StringBuilder endingLetters = new StringBuilder(new string(letterZ, length));

    int currentIndex = length - 1;

    while (currentLetters.ToString() != endingLetters.ToString())
    {
        yield return currentLetters.ToString();

        for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (currentLetters[i] == letterZ)
            {
                for (int j = i; j < length; j++)
                {
                    currentLetters[j] = letterA;
                }

                if (currentLetters[i - 1] != letterZ)
                {
                    currentLetters[i - 1]++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                currentLetters[i]++;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756055/listing-all-permutations-of-a-string-integer)

Comment: Also take a look at this question [Generate list of all possible permutations of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For a variable amount of letter combinations, you can do the following:

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var q = alphabet.Select(x => x.ToString());
int size = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    q = q.SelectMany(x => alphabet, (x, y) => x + y);

foreach (var item in q)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Comment: I know this is pretty old but you could have used LINQ to print out the array.

`q.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));`

Comment: @JasonHeddle There is no ForEach extension for IEnumerable.

Comment: then all you would have to do is add `.ToArray()` before the `.Foreach`, like so: `q.ToArray().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Comment: @JasonHeddle - `ForEach` method is specific for List<T>. What is the problem with this _foreach_?

Answer (score 14):

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
//or var alphabet = Enumerable.Range('a', 'z' - 'a' + 1).Select(i => (char)i);

var query = from a in alphabet
            from b in alphabet
            from c in alphabet
            select "" + a + b + c;

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

***_*_EDIT_*_***

For a general solution, you can use the [CartesianProduct here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx)

```
int N = 4;
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(_ => alphabet).CartesianProduct();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("",item));
}
```

---

```
// Eric Lippert’s Blog
// Computing a Cartesian Product with LINQ
// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    // base case: 
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> result = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    foreach (var sequence in sequences)
    {
        var s = sequence; // don't close over the loop variable 
        // recursive case: use SelectMany to build the new product out of the old one 
        result =
            from seq in result
            from item in s
            select seq.Concat(new[] { item });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised but yes, this works.

Comment: I thought of something like this but what if I have a variable amount of possible letter combinations? I just used 3 as an example. Might need to be 4 or 5

Comment: @RyanPeschel than use [CartesianProduct here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) giving it n alphabet.

Answer (score 4):

You have 26^3 counts for 3 "digits". Just iterate from 'a' to 'z' in three loops.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very simple solution:

```
for(char first = 'a'; first <= (int)'z'; first++)
    for(char second = 'a'; second <= (int)'z'; second++)
        for(char third = 'a'; third <= (int)'z'; third++)
            Console.WriteLine(first.ToString() + second + third);
```