# How to generate a file with all possible 12 character letter/number combinations?

Tags: c#, generator, letters-and-numbers

I have been struggling with this for some time, and I can't even figure out where could I start with it.
I am trying to create a program that is going to generate a lot of random (I could call them serials).
Limit would be from letter A-Z on english uppercase alphabet and numbers from 0-9.

Something like website application at this page http://www.random.org/strings/

but

I would like it to create "all" combinations, none same, of letters and numbers, and save them to text file. I think there are around 200k+ combinations.

They would be 12 characters. Example:

- T9T1P63WBYYZ
- SCI1V7SAV9F5
- 5OLN7UQS7MIE

I would like to create it in C# if it is possible, but I have no idea where should I even start.
I'm browsing google and similar projects for around a week, and I need it as university project.
If someone would help I would be very happy.

Comment: 12 characters string would give you 36^12 possible combination, not 2^6. Which (given that we have 2 bytes per character) will result in a file of around 105 billion terabytes

Comment: Do you need it for a one time generation?  Meaning you don't have to try and reproduce the number at a later time?  Also - does it have to go through a validation to ensure the "serial" is valid?  Have you looked at the GUID classes?

Comment: ... and assuming you can generate *`1` million* elements per second, will take *`150` thousands* years.

Comment: Think about just the numbers, not the letters. All possible combinations of numbers less than a certain length is easy to compute: the number of twelve-character strings made out of numbers is 1000000000000 -- twelve zeros. By what logic are you computing that there are 200000 such strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hehe.. if you have the time!**

Asked yesterday, seen a great solution by **L.B** here:

[How to get all the possible 3 letter permutations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891200/how-to-get-all-the-possible-3-letter-combinations)

His simple solution, just change the alphabet:

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";

var query = from a in alphabet
            from b in alphabet
            from c in alphabet
            from d in alphabet
            from e in alphabet
            from f in alphabet
            from g in alphabet
            from h in alphabet
            from i in alphabet
            from j in alphabet
            from k in alphabet
            from l in alphabet

            select "" + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l;

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

A more advanced answer might be the [CartesianProduct](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx)

Comment: -1. THat does not generate the file of 66337338736502636544 Bytes.