# Finding unique letter combinations within a word

Tags: c#, arrays, combinations

I'm trying to find all the unique letter combinations, of 3 or more letters, in the word "several" using C#.

I only have the code to break it down into an array, but I can't figure out an algorithm to make combinations of it.

```
class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            string s = "several";
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
       }
    }
```

Comment: are you looking for "real" words, or just combinations of 3 or more characters?

Comment: there are numerous examples of string permutation algorithms out there.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891200/how-to-get-all-the-possible-3-letter-permutations