# How to find all possible strings of a certain length using only the chars out of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops, character

Sorry if this is a duplicate. It's hard to precisely ask what I need on Google without showing examples.

I want to use an array of chars that are the allowed characters, and then use a method (that has a length parameter) to return a list of all the possible strings using these allowed characters.

For example, if the char[] would contain `'A', 'B', 'C'` and the given length would be 3 then the results would be

```
AAA, AAB, AAC,
ABA, ABB, ABC,
ACA, ACB, ACC,
BAA, BAB, BAC,
BBA, BBB, BBC,
BCA, BCB, BCC,
CAA, CAB, CAC,
CBA, CBB, CBC,
CCA, CCB, CCC
```

An exact  answer with code is not necessary, as I'm trying to make this out of pure interest and for enjoyment, so hints are welcome to!

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891200/how-to-get-all-the-possible-3-letter-permutations

Comment: What I needed, thank you Ehsan Sajjad. Are you just better at googling than I am or did you read this question before?

Comment: i read it before for my problem scenario as well..:)