# Getting all unique permutations of a set filled with 2 different characters w/ limits

Tags: c#, algorithm

So I've searched around and honestly can't find a solution.

I'm completely lost, having one of those days.

Let's say I have this set

```
string[] arr = { "N", "N", "N", "N", "O", "O", "O", "O" };
```

I want to find all possible unique permutations, where there are never more "O"s than "N"s preceding it.

I.e If at index `[2]`, 1 `"N"` and 1 `"O"` have been already come before it, then `arr[2]` must hold an `"N"`. `["N","O","N",...]`

I want to write a function that can output a 2D array of all permutations that follow these rules for any sized set.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How big can the input be? Given that there are only two types of input at any point, I'd be tempted to just treat each potential permutation as an integer (considering it in binary with N=1 and O=0 or vice versa) and just run through all integers in the possible range to see whether they fit - but that will only scale so far.

Comment: @DaisyShipton this was one of my first thoughts, but the more I thought about it the more complicated it seemed. What pattern of loops/iterations would provide me with a definitive set of unique permutations? I swear my brain's gone to mush today.

Comment: If there is a duplication it's not a "set"

Comment: @VladiPavelka Sorry for using the wrong terminology, i guess i just meant an array/group. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @MattyB sounds like an interview question : ) I'll give it a try

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/13891349/468973 can help.

Comment: If you regard every possible permutation as an integer, looping through them all is trivial: you just use a normal `for` loop from 0 to the highest value (e.g. 255 in the example, as there are 8 bits per value). You'd then validate that it has the right number of bits set, and their positions.

Comment: Very unfortunate question close : / I was in the middle of writing a 2 page-downs explanation of different versions of solution algo and its algorithmic complexities

Comment: @Vladi Pavelka This is well-known problem with numerous descriptions and analysis (Catalan numbers). If you think you have new useful information, I can try to reopen (not sure it is possible)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ypQ9Erwm

Comment: @MBo I was just disappointed I got cut off, but it's ok : )

Comment: @MattyB check the pastebin link

Comment: @VladiPavelka Thanks! I'll look over it now. Thanks for taking the time to go through this.

Comment: @MattyB welcome! : )