# Generate all combinations of 10 digits without any repetition

Tags: java, random

I am having an assignment about creating password through Java:

> Suppose you work in a safe selling company and your manager asked you to create a list of all the ten digit numbers between 0000000000 and 9999999999 without repeating a digit in the same number. What is the method to do this algorithm in JAVA?

Here's what I've done so far:

```
public static long generateNumber()  
{  
    String s1 = "33333";  
    double d = Math.random();  
    d=d*100000.0;  
    int i = (int) d;  
    String s2 = String.valueOf(i);  
    String s3=s1+s2;  
    long m = Long.parseLong(s3);  
    return m;
}
```

Comment: I'd probably consider shuffling a collection of the digits.

Comment: Your program always gives you a number, that starts with 33333, so it repeats the digit 3, apart from that, it gives you only a single number, not all numbers

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for ten digit numbers without any duplicate digits, you're effectively looking to generate all permutations of all digits, i.e. the string `"0123456789"`.

There are other threads on SO to help you with this, for example these

- [Generating all permutations of a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string)
- [Generate list of all possible permutations of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string)

Comment: no i don't want permutations i am asked to generate all the 10 digits numbers between 0000000000 & 9999999999 using array & random method

Comment: @OmarMustafa This request is bullshit, there is no guarantee that a random method generates **all** elements.

Comment: Omar, you stated that you wanted all numbers but `without repeating a digit in the same number`! Nothing about arrays, and nothing about "random method".

Approaches using random elements is useless in this case, as it's never guaranteed to produce sufficient diverse input - a random number generator could (in theory) spit out only the number 2 forever...

If you want 10-digit numbers without any repeating digits, well: that's the same thing as all permutations of the string "0123456789" as I posted above.

Comment: Generating all possible strings is not the same as generating all possible combinations of 10 digits without repetition. Strings may contain non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

A simplstic way that uses little code is:

```
List<Long> combos = new ArrayList<>();
Set<Character> chars = new HashSet<>();
for (long i = 1000000000; i < 9999999999L; i++) {
    chars.clear();
    for (char c : String.valueOf(i).toCharArray()) {
        chars.add(c);
    }
    if ((chars).size() == 10) {
        combos.add(i);
    }
}
```

Not very effeicient, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Using a shuffling technique:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> passwords = Arrays.asList( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 );
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
        {
            Collections.shuffle(passwords);
            String p = toFlatString(passwords);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }

    private static String toFlatString(List<Integer> list) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i : list)
            sb.append(i);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

**Output:**
2651803497
2936745018
7064918235
1594670823
4035872619
6432971850
6387925401
7103649285
9712380645
9321574806

Comment: this way is good but i want a list of all the numbers that can be generated

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since the question is asking how to generate all possible permutations. This implemention only generates a handful of the possible permutations.