# Java Permutations of String given an Integer Number

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer, permutation

I am trying to do permutations in java of a String given an Integer Number.

So if the String is "abc" and the Integer Number is 2.

I want the following results:

ab
ac
ba
bc
ca
cb

If the String is also "abc" but the Integer Number is 3, I want the following results:

abc
bac
cba
bca
cab
acb

I have already the following method:

```
private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
        int n = str.length();
        if (n == 0) permutationsList.add(prefix);
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
        }
    }
```

But this only works for the Integer Number equals to the String size, in this case 3.

So can something help me to make this work, with a Integer argument?

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Comment: I suppose this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best way to do permutation of a data set is to by applying [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) , it help making all combination of a specified length .

Here is my solution for your problem :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author mifmif
 * 
 */
public class DFS {

    /**
     * list of generated combination
     */
    List<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>();
    /**
     * input used to generate combination
     */
    String input = "ABCDEF";
    /**
     * the length of the combination
     */
    int conbinationSize = 3;
    /**
     * isChoosed[i] is true if the combination that is currently prepared
     * contain index.charAt(i)
     */
    boolean[] isChoosed = new boolean[input.length()];

    /**
     * the DFS method that will generate all possible combination
     * 
     * @param partialOutput
     */
    public void generateCombination(String partialOutput) {
        if (partialOutput.length() == conbinationSize) {
            permutations.add(partialOutput);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
            if (!isChoosed[i]) {
                isChoosed[i] = true;
                generateCombination(partialOutput + input.charAt(i));
                isChoosed[i] = false;
            }
        }

    }

    void printCombination() {
        for (String c : permutations) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DFS dfs = new DFS();
        dfs.generateCombination("");
        dfs.printCombination();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back from your IDE/editor and think about how to solve this problem in pseudocode, at a higher level.

What should happen if the length of the string is zero or the integer `k` is zero?
How do you get the permutations if `k` is equal to the length of the string? If your string is `'ABC'` you would get all the permutations starting with `'A'` by finding all the permutations of `'BC'` and appending each of them to the letter `'A'`. So what happens now in order to to get the permutations of `'ABC'` starting with `'B'` and `'C'`?

Finally, ask yourself at what step you would need to stop the process if `k` is smaller than the length of the string.

Some pseudo-code:

```
perms(string, k)
    if length(string) == 0 or k == 0
         // do what?
    else
       for every character in string
           for every sub-permutation in perms(*some modified string*, *some modified k-value*)
                // the permutation is character + sub-permutation
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am so slow today . I can not think well . I know that if length(string) == 0 or k == 0 I need to return empty String right? But for the other case I don't know :s

Comment: Yes, a zero-length string or a k value of zero is your simple case for which the permutation would be the empty string. Another hint: the sub-permutation should reduce in size each recursive call. If that's not clear try to understand the version of the function which does not take a k parameter first. What should happen to k now? Would it not be great if k reached zero before the length of the *some modified string* reached zero?