# Calculate the number of unique strings that can be made from a string

Tags: python, string

If I have a string (e.g. 'AABC'), how can I calculate the number of possible unique strings?

The answer is 12 in this case, but how can I caclulate this with an algorithm?

I could do it for 'ABC', but having the repeated character confuses me.

I'm trying to do it in Python

Edit: Also, I am not looking to generate all the possible strings, only to calculate the number.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string

Comment: I don't think those are applicable. I tried some and given 'AABC' it will generate multiple of the same string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could walk through all the permutations and count the unique one using the itertools module

```
import itertools

string = "AABC"
count = len(set(itertools.permutations(string)))
print(count)
```

But since you just need the count, you can do that a bit more easily:

```
import math
import collections

string = "AABC"

chars = collections.Counter(string)
denominator = reduce(lambda x,y: x * math.factorial(y), chars.values(), 1)
count = math.factorial(len(string)) / denominator
print(count)
```

Comment: s/a bit more easily/more efficiently/

Comment: Wow, that is super impressive and seems correct, a bit of googling leads me to believe it has something to do with binomial coefficients, but the wikipedia article is way beyond me. In laymans terms, could you explain it?

Comment: Say you have n unique items (alphabets in this case), and you want to count the total number of ways you can arrange them. There are n ways to select the first item for an arrangement, then (n - 1) ways to select the second, then (n - 2) for the third and so on. So the total number of arrangements becomes n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * ... * 1. Or in other words, n!.

Comment: Now say some of those items are duplicates. In the OP's example, there are 2 As. Following the same logic as above, there are 2! ways to arrange these 2 As, but they will generate duplicate arrangements. So you'll end up with "AABC" and "AACB" repeated 2! times. Simply divide by 2! to get the unique arrangements. To generalize, if the n items contain n1 items of one type, n2 of another, etc. the number of unique arrangements is n!/(n1!*n2!...)

Comment: Thanks linus, that is an excellent answer and explanation and if I could make StackOverflow dispense beer directly to you, I would, but you'll have to make do with an accepted answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with itertools module.

Open up your python interpreter.

```
import itertools
for unique in itertools.permutations("AABC"):
    print "".join(unique)
```

Just change "AABC" with whatever you want.

Comment: You haven't noticed the word ***unique*** in the question title.

Comment: **Hint** what's the main property of a `set`? Its elements are ***unique***.  How do you make a `set` from an iterable? `set(iterable)`.  Is a `set` an iterable? Oh yes.

Comment: Thanks, but for large strings, this is going to be extremely time consuming when all that is required is the count. linus nailed it above.

Comment: Hey thanks gbofi, I just noticed that the output strings are not unique.

Comment: @bleurhgarator - yeah for large strings this will consume a lot of time and yeah linus really  nailed it