# Building a math game in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I am building a math game for java and I'm stuck at this part as per the details of my assignment. The rules are simple: you have to use each number only once and only the 4 numbers that were read from the user to find one equation to obtain 24.

For example, for the numbers 4,7,8,8, a possible solution is: (7-(8/8))*4=24.

Most sets of 4 digits can be used in multiple equations that result in 24. For example the input 2,2,4,7 can be used in multiple ways to obtain 24:

2+2*(4+7) = 24

2+2*(7+4) = 24

(2+2)*7-4 = 24

(2*2)*7-4 = 24

2*(2*7)-4 = 24

There are also combinations of 4 numbers that cannot result into any equation equal with 24. For example 1,1,1,1. In this case, your program should return that there is no possible equation equal with 24.

Note: Although we will enter 4 integers between 1 and 9, we will use doubles to compute all the operations. For example, the numbers 3,3,8,8 can be combined into the formula: 8/(3-8/3) = 24.

Workflow: Your program should read the 4 numbers from the user and output a formula that results in 24. The algorithm should enumerate all the possible orders of 4 numbers, all the possible combinations and all the possible formulas.

Which leads me to 24 permutations of Numbers a,b,c,d and 64 permutations of operators `+-/*`. How I came to this conclusion was 4^3 4 operators only 3 fill spots in the equation. Except today I am having trouble writing the evaluation method and also accounting for parentases in the equations.

Here is my code:

```
public static void evaluate(cbar [][] operations , double [][] operands)
{
    /*
    This is the part that gets me how am I supposed to account
    for parentases and bring all these expressions togather to
    actually form and equation.
    */
}
```

Comment: Quick question, is it absolutely necessary to include a case `a + b` if you already have the case `b + a`? If it isn't required, this could be reduced and the parenthesis handled fairly easily.

Comment: Its this an homework?

Comment: ya it is a homework assignment  and also is there any way to create an evaluation method?

Answer (score 10):

This problem presents several challenges. My solution below is about two hundred lines long. It's probably a little longer than the assignment requires because I generalized it to any number of terms. I encourage you to study the algorithm and write your own solution.

The main obstacles we must overcome are the following.

- How do we generate permutations without repetition?
- How do we build and evaluate arithmetic expressions?
- How do we convert the expressions into unique strings?

There are many ways to generate permutations. I chose a recursive approach because it's easy to understand. The main complication is that terms can be repeated, which means that there may be fewer than `4! = 4*3*2*1` permutations. For example, if the terms are `1 1 1 2`, there are only four permutations.

To avoid duplicating permutations, we start by sorting the terms. The recursive function finds places for all duplicate terms from left to right without backtracking. For example, once the first `1` has been placed in the array, all the remaining `1` terms are placed to the right of it. But when we get to a `2` term, we can go back to the beginning of the array.

To build arithmetic expressions, we use another recursive function. This function looks at each position between two terms of the permutation, splitting the array into a segment to the left of the position and a segment to the right. It makes a pair of recursive calls to build expressions for the left and right segments. Finally, it joins the resulting child expressions with each of the four arithmetic operators. The base case is when the array is of size one, so it can't be split. This results in a node with no operator and no children, only a value.

Evaluating the expressions by performing arithmetic on `double` values would be problematic due to the imprecision of floating-point division. For example, `1.0 / 3 = 0.33333...`, but `3 * 0.33333... = 0.99999...`. This makes it difficult to know for sure that `1 / 3 * 3 = 1` when you're using `double` values. To avoid these difficulties, I defined a `Fraction` class. It performs arithmetic operations on fractions and always simplifies the result by means of the greatest common divisor. Division by zero does not result in an error message. Instead, we store the fraction 0/0.

The final piece of the puzzle is converting expressions into strings. We want to make canonical or normalized strings so that we don't repeat ourselves needlessly. For example, we don't want to display `1 + (1 + (1 + 2))` and `((1 + 1) + 1) + 2`, since these are essentially the same expression. Instead of showing all possible parenthesizations, we just want to display `1 + 1 + 1 + 2`.

We can achieve this by adding parentheses only when necessary. To wit, parentheses are necessary if a node with a higher-priority operator (multiplication or division) is the parent of a node with a lower-priority operator (addition or subtraction). By priority I mean operator precedence, also known as the order of operations. The higher-priority operators bind more tightly than the lower ones. So if a parent node has higher priority than the operator of a child node, it is necessary to parenthesize the child. To ensure that we end up with unique strings, we check them against a hash set before adding them to the result list.

The following program, `Equation.java`, accepts user input on the command line. The parameters of the game are on the first line of the `Equation` class. You can modify these to build expressions with more terms, bigger terms, and different target values.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Fraction {                  // Avoids floating-point trouble.
  int num, denom;
  static int gcd(int a, int b) {  // Greatest common divisor.
    while (b != 0) {
      int t = b;
      b = a % b;
      a = t;
    }
    return a;
  }
  Fraction(int num, int denom) {  // Makes a simplified fraction.
    if (denom == 0) {             // Division by zero results in
      this.num = this.denom = 0;  //  the fraction 0/0. We do not
    } else {                      //  throw an error.
      int x = Fraction.gcd(num, denom);
      this.num = num / x;
      this.denom = denom / x;     
    }
  }
  Fraction plus(Fraction other) {
    return new Fraction(this.num * other.denom + other.num * this.denom,
        this.denom * other.denom);
  }
  Fraction minus(Fraction other) {
    return this.plus(new Fraction(-other.num, other.denom));
  }
  Fraction times(Fraction other) {
    return new Fraction(this.num * other.num, this.denom * other.denom);
  }
  Fraction divide(Fraction other) {
    return new Fraction(this.num * other.denom, this.denom * other.num);
  }
  public String toString() {      // Omits the denominator if possible.
    if (denom == 1) {
      return ""+num;
    }
    return num+"/"+denom;
  }
}

class Expression {                // A tree node containing a value and
  Fraction value;                 //  optionally an operator and its
  String operator;                //  operands.
  Expression left, right;
  static int level(String operator) {
    if (operator.compareTo("+") == 0 || operator.compareTo("-") == 0) {
      return 0;                   // Returns the priority of evaluation,
    }                             //  also known as operator precedence
    return 1;                     //  or the order of operations.
  }
  Expression(int x) {             // Simplest case: a whole number.
    value = new Fraction(x, 1);
  }
  Expression(Expression left, String operator, Expression right) {
    if (operator == "+") {
      value = left.value.plus(right.value);
    } else if (operator == "-") {
      value = left.value.minus(right.value);
    } else if (operator == "*") {
      value = left.value.times(right.value);
    } else if (operator == "/") {
      value = left.value.divide(right.value);
    }
    this.operator = operator;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }
  public String toString() {      // Returns a normalized expression,
    if (operator == null) {       //  inserting parentheses only where
      return value.toString();    //  necessary to avoid ambiguity.
    }
    int level = Expression.level(operator);
    String a = left.toString(), aOp = left.operator,
           b = right.toString(), bOp = right.operator;
    if (aOp != null && Expression.level(aOp) < level) {
      a = "("+a+")";              // Parenthesize the child only if its
    }                             //  priority is lower than the parent's.
    if (bOp != null && Expression.level(bOp) < level) {
      b = "("+b+")";
    }
    return a + " " + operator + " " + b;
  }
}

public class Equation {

  // These are the parameters of the game.
  static int need = 4, min = 1, max = 9, target = 24;

  int[] terms, permutation;
  boolean[] used;
  ArrayList<String> wins = new ArrayList<String>();
  Set<String> winSet = new HashSet<String>();
  String[] operators = {"+", "-", "*", "/"};

  // Recursively break up the terms into left and right
  //  portions, joining them with one of the four operators.
  ArrayList<Expression> make(int left, int right) {
    ArrayList<Expression> result = new ArrayList<Expression>();
    if (left+1 == right) {
      result.add(new Expression(permutation[left]));
    } else {
      for (int i = left+1; i < right; ++i) {
        ArrayList<Expression> leftSide = make(left, i);
        ArrayList<Expression> rightSide = make(i, right);
        for (int j = 0; j < leftSide.size(); ++j) {
          for (int k = 0; k < rightSide.size(); ++k) {
            for (int p = 0; p < operators.length; ++p) {
              result.add(new Expression(leftSide.get(j),
                    operators[p],
                    rightSide.get(k)));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  // Given a permutation of terms, form all possible arithmetic
  //  expressions. Inspect the results and save those that
  //  have the target value.
  void formulate() {
    ArrayList<Expression> expressions = make(0, terms.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < expressions.size(); ++i) {
      Expression expression = expressions.get(i);
      Fraction value = expression.value;
      if (value.num == target && value.denom == 1) {
        String s = expressions.get(i).toString();
        if (!winSet.contains(s)) {// Check to see if an expression
          wins.add(s);            //  with the same normalized string
          winSet.add(s);          //  representation was saved earlier.
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Permutes terms without duplication. Requires the terms to
  //  be sorted. Notice how we check the next term to see if
  //  it's the same. If it is, we don't return to the beginning
  //  of the array.
  void permute(int termIx, int pos) {
    if (pos == terms.length) {
      return;
    }
    if (!used[pos]) {
      permutation[pos] = terms[termIx];
      if (termIx+1 == terms.length) {
        formulate();
      } else {
        used[pos] = true;
        if (terms[termIx+1] == terms[termIx]) {
          permute(termIx+1, pos+1);
        } else {
          permute(termIx+1, 0);
        }
        used[pos] = false;
      }
    }
    permute(termIx, pos+1);
  }

  // Start the permutation process, count the end results, display them.
  void solve(int[] terms) {
    this.terms = terms;           // We must sort the terms in order for
    Arrays.sort(terms);           //  the permute() function to work.
    permutation = new int[terms.length];
    used = new boolean[terms.length];
    permute(0, 0);
    if (wins.size() == 0) {
      System.out.println("There are no feasible expressions.");
    } else if (wins.size() == 1) {
      System.out.println("There is one feasible expression:");
    } else {
      System.out.println("There are "+wins.size()+" feasible expressions:");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wins.size(); ++i) {
      System.out.println(wins.get(i) + " = " + target);
    }
  }

  // Get user input from the command line and check its validity.
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != need) {
      System.out.println("must specify "+need+" digits");
      return;
    }
    int digits[] = new int[need];
    for (int i = 0; i < need; ++i) {
      try {
        digits[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("\""+args[i]+"\" is not an integer");
        return;
      }
      if (digits[i] < min || digits[i] > max) {
        System.out.println(digits[i]+" is outside the range ["+
            min+", "+max+"]");
        return;
      }
    }
    (new Equation()).solve(digits);
  }
}
```

Comment: what changes should be made if %, <<, >> , &, | , ^ are also valid operators?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to use a tree structure to store the equation, i.e. a syntactic tree in which the root represents and operator having two children representing the operands and so on recursively. You would probably get a cleaner code doing it like that, because then you won't need to generate the combinations of operands "by hand", but you can make a code which picks every operand from a 1-dimensional char[] operands = new char[] {'+','-','*','/'} array.

If you don't want to use a syntactic tree or think it's not necessary for your use case you can always try to find a different way to make the code to pick operands from the 1-dimensional array and store them into a different data structure. But I would especially avoid writing all the combinations as you are doing. It does not look very easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the similar puzzle with below code.

```
public static boolean game24Points(int[] operands) {
    ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = sem.getEngineByName("javascript");

    char[] operations = new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                try {
                    String exp = "" + operands[0] + operations[i] + operands[1] + operations[j]
                            + operands[2] + operations[k] + operands[3];
                    String res = engine.eval(exp).toString();
                    if (Double.valueOf(res).intValue() == 24) {
                        System.out.println(exp);
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (ScriptException e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here are testcases

```
public void testCase01() {
    int[] operands = { 7, 2, 1, 10 };
    assertEquals(true, Demo.game24Points(operands));
}

public void testCase02() {
    int[] operands = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    assertEquals(true, Demo.game24Points(operands));
}

public void testCase03() {
    int[] operands1 = { 5, 7, 12, 12 };
    assertEquals(true, Demo.game24Points(operands1));
    int[] operands = { 10, 3, 3, 23 };
    assertEquals(true, Demo.game24Points(operands));
}
```