# What's an algorithm to print the permutations of a string with much efficiency?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

The algorithm which I know is the below but why I hate this approach is it's time complexity is O((n+1)!) too worse in case of large strings

> > Start by sorting the string and printing that as the first permutation.
> >     Now, we can find the next permutation as follows:
> >
> > Let i be the last index such that input[i] < input[i + 1]. If there is no such index, then we’re done.
> >         Let j be the last index such that input[i] < input[j].
> >         Swap input[i] with input[j].
> >         Reverse input[i + 1] through input[input.length - 1].

Is there any better approach than the above one ?(If explanation is through code then please consider c or c++)... just I am expecting a better algorithm with lesser time complexity than the above one

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string

Answer (score 6):

There are `n!` permutations for a string with length `n`. Simply printing them is `O(n * n!)`, how can you expect it will be much more efficient?

Comment: Unless there are duplicate letters, then there are less than `n!` permutations.

Comment: ya ,I know that but I had some hope, may be there can be any chances of getting much better one.

Comment: It's actually O(n*n!), since each print is itself O(n)

Answer (score 3):

Even the standard C++ implementation to print permutations of a string follows exactly same algorithm ([std::next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) and [std::prev_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/prev_permutation))

```
std::string s;
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
do {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
} while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in C++ the STL has std::next_permutation that does the job you need