# python all possibility from lenth k question

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have this code and i want it randomly generation not in orders like aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac
i want to start randomly exemple: a025b9c87e84d6454 not aaaaaaaaaac
can anyone help me with that ?

```
def printAllKLength(set, k): 
    n = len(set) 
    printAllKLengthRec(set, "", n, k) 

def printAllKLengthRec(set, prefix, n, k):
    if (k == 0) : 
        print(prefix) 
        return

    for i in range(n): 
        newPrefix = prefix + set[i]         
        printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix, n, k-1) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("First Test") 
    set1 = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'] 
    k = 20
    printAllKLength(set1, k)
```

Comment: Please use python docs and research

Comment: Look into permutation methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate list of all possible permutations of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from itertools import product
from random import shuffle

k = 3 # this should be 20 in your case
chars = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
         '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

p = list(product(chars, repeat=k))
shuffle(p)

result = map(''.join, p)

print(*result, sep='\n')
```

Result:

```
542
718
849
2FA
FFA
940
065
7AD
335
327
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = 5
s = 'a','b','c',1,2,9,5
res = ["".join(i) for i in itertools.permutations(map(str, s), x]
```

`res` will have your list. `s` has the possible input characters. `x` is the length of each generated string.

Comment: thats not working,
is there any code to generate x lenth specific letters a,b,c,1,2,9,5 
generate all possibility randomly